# Unable to install libraries/packages through Ananconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have downloaded and installed Python (3.9), and Anaconda3. I use Jupyter lab/notebook as my IDE.

I have been trying to install some basic libraries through both the Ananconda Navigator and the Anaconda prompt (Ananconda3). I keep getting this same error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -


An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64'
```

I do work for an organization, but I have tried several solutions both on the VPN and on my own home wifi.

I am not working from behind a proxy.

I have set the ssl_verify to false.

I have copied these two libraries from one folder to another:

libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.dll

Anaconda3/Library/bin to Anaconda3/DLLs

Here is my conda info.

```
active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\XXXX\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\XXXX\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\XXXX\.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : 3.21.6
         python version : 3.9.7.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=11.0=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\439528\Anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\XXXX\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\XXXX\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\XXXX\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\XXXX\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.9.7 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19042
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

I've tried to do a conda update (same error)
I've tried to install different things (plotly, tensorflow, keras)

Comment: Can you access the data the repodata (https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/repodata.json.bz2) from outside of Conda?

Comment: I have the same issue behind my company firewall. Simplest solution is to download the packages manually and take care of the necessary dependencies as you go.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, can you elaborate on how to do this manually? I am fairly new to anaconda/python/coding in general. In my degree program, the environments are always set up for us, so this is all new territory for me.

Comment: @merv, when i click on that link, it gives me a page of symbols and 'gibberish'. I gather that is not supposed to be the case?

Comment: @tminn. No, that's right. Go up to the directory, right click and download the file. BZ2 is a compressed archive that contains your package contents.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, okay, i downloaded it. What do I do with it, lol?

Comment: Google is your best friend. Try "install conda package from bz2" or similar. Look for a post that involves a command like "conda install <some options> <your bz2 file>". It will likely fail because of dependency issues, at which point you will have to go and download the missing dependencies in the same way. Then those files will have missing dependencies. Once you have iterated to where you have everything you need, you'll be able to install the package you actually want.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, thanks! but i get the conda http error for ANYTHING i try to do "conda install" for. even conda updates. both through the command prompt and anaconda navigator.

Comment: Right. Did you run a command to install from a offline file?

Comment: And if that doesn't work, try PyPi and pip instead of conda. Conda will work with pip-installed packages just fine

Comment: To clarify: I only wanted to suggested manually checking ability to access the repodata.json file to verify that the domain is not blocked on your network. Since it isn’t, you should be able to getting `conda install` working directly. I was not advocating manually downloading the repodata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up needing to go through an exception process in order to get past my company's firewall.